# How to select radio button with Capybara using Poltergeist?

Tags: capybara, poltergeist

HTML:

```
<div id='survey'>
  Name:<input type='text' name='name'><br>
  Like sushi?<input type="radio" name="sushi" value="yes">Yes 
             <input type="radio" name="sushi" value="no">No
</div>
```

Spec:

```
within 'div#survey' do
  fill_in 'name', with:'Joe Brown'
  choose 'no'
end
```

This raises the exception:

```
 Failure/Error: choose 'no'
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find radio button "no"
```

How to select the radio button "no"?

Answer (score 1):

Try with choose 'NO' as the label text is in caps.

Comment: I hope I had already tried that. `Unable to find radio button "No"`